# H is a transitive subgroup of $S_n$. Prove that |H| is a multiple of n.

Tags: group-theory

Any ideas on how to prove the above?
All I have shown is that H must have at least n elements and we know that $|H||n!$

i.e. For all n in $S_n$ there exists $T_1 \in H$ s.t. $T_1(1)=n$

Comment: This follows from the [Orbit Stabilizer Theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Orbit-stabilizer_theorem)

Comment: @lulu Is the group here H and the set {1,..,n} with the action being f(i)?

Comment: I don't know what $f$ is.  Yes, $H$ is the group and yes the underlying set is $\{1,\cdots, n\}$.  $H$ acts on that set via permutations.

Comment: as in f is an element of h

Answer (score 1):

The orbit stabiliser theorem implies that $H$ must have a subgroup of index $n$. The result follows immediately.

Comment: What the group and set here?

Comment: @lulu Is the group here H and the set {1,..,n} with the action being f(i)?